# Purple dot near app which downloaded by iCloud sync

Tags: iphone

I added my account to my old iPad mini and I downloaded this app on it. Then, I used my iPhone and saw that the app downloaded too on it. Is the purple dot DOES mean that it downloaded by sync? And can I shut this feature off?
[image]

Comment: I agree with @mark that it’s probably a blue dot, meaning the app hasn’t yet been opened since being downloaded.  Yes you can turn off automatic downloads by going to Settings > iTunes and App Store.

Answer (score 1):

A blue dot before an apps' icon name means that it has not bee run yet (or it is a new version that has not been run).

An orange dot means that the app was downloaded as a beta as installed through Testflight.

The last is from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26801503/151019) which also suggests the colours alter if on a different background.

Try a plain black or white background to see if the colour changes to one of these known ones.